# How many sheep I have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I divide my flock of sheep into two subflocks of different sizes. The difference between the sizes of the subflocks is equal to the difference between the squares of their sizes How many sheep do I have altogether.

Comment: The problem needs clarification as to whether the two different parts must have a different number of sheep or not.  Also, some people are wondering where you got this problem.

Comment: I have found this problem in an olympiad .

Comment: @breeden: As I tried to explain in my answer to JiK's comment, clarification on that point isn't needed. By trying the division of $a-b$ from both sides of the equation representing the condition on the size of the subflocks, you see that either the problem has solution $S = 1$, or it does not have a solution. Then, if $S = 1$, and because fractional sheep are surely not in the spirit of the question, necessarily $a \neq b$.

Comment: True, so I guess it _does_ require that you divide the sheep into two non-empty groupings :)

Comment: Way to infinity, this definitely does not seem like an olympiad problem.  What do you mean by olympiad problem?

Comment: This is a question from low class . I have solved it . i have also got answer 1 . But then I think that how can I divide the 1 sheep into two sub-groups ? I have thought that I have done a mistake .

Comment: One subgroup of size 1, one subgroup of size 0

Comment: @breeden: as JiK has pointed out to me, I've missed the obvious fact that if $a=b$, then in fact *every* value of $S$ works, so perhaps the clarification is needed after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation below represents dividing your flock into different parts. The second equation below is the statement that the difference between the numbers is the same as the difference of their squares.

$$a+b = S$$
$$a-b = a^2 - b^2$$

Rewrite the second equation:

$$a-b = (a-b)(a+b)$$

And, since $a \neq b$, so that $a-b \neq 0$, then divide $a-b$ from both sides and apply the first equation at the top of this post:

$$1 = a +b = S.$$

$S = 1$ is the number of sheep.

Comment: Since I'm being downvoted, can someone please explain what it is that I've done incorrectly so I can correct my answer?

Comment: (a) What if the division was not legal? (b) You are giving a complete answer to an apparent homework question rather than asking more info from the OP or guiding him into the right direction, which is frowned upon by some people here.

Comment: (a) is irrelevant as the last line demonstrates, for if S = 1, then there is no way to write $a+b = 1$ with integer $a, b$ such that $a-b = 0$. Furthermore, if someone believed that were a problem with the answer that should have been phrased as a comment rather than a downvote.

(b) is not a reason to downvote, as the answer was clearly not "not useful" by virtue of being complete, and furthermore the assumption that the question is a homework problem is overly-prejudicial.

Comment: JiK, are you sure it is a homework problem?  Is giving complete answers all together frowned upon, or for when people explicitly state that it's not a homework problem.  Or is it just understood that people with algebra questions don't come here to ask genuine non-homework questions?  Just curious, as I haven't been here long.

Comment: Jik , I have to say you are completely fool . I am engineer and love to solve math problem . You cant say me that I am doing homework .

Comment: I'm not sure it is a homework problem, I only suggested it might be a reason. Now I see that I clearly phrased it wrong, I didn't mean to be rude. Sorry about that :)

Comment: More on the answer: You are first assuming that $a\neq b$, and then from the answer you get, you are deducing that $a \neq b$, but that is circular reasoning. E.g. $a=b=42$ is another solution to the equation $a-b=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: It is not. By assuming $S \neq 1$, we get $a-b = (a-b)S$, which is false unless $S = 0$, which seems against the spirit of the question. Hence, we can use the fact that $S = 1$ to conclude that $a\neq b$. I will update the phrasing of my answer to reflect this.

Comment: But $a-b=(a-b)S$ is true also when $a=b$?

Comment: Interesting. I'll concede that I was definitely overlooking the obvious. But in that case, any value of $S$ will do, which makes this either a trick question or a silly question. Perhaps it is the case, then, that the original question should exclude that possibility.

Comment: Jik , thanks for your interests to help improvement of my questions . @ Nick , calm down . This site will be helpful to all math lovers for helpful mentality of math expert like Nick and Jik . Many many thanks bot both of you .

Answer (score 3):

You have just one sheep. For if you divide your sheep into two parts with $a$ and $b$ number of sheep, then 
$$a-b=a^{2} - b^{2} \implies (a-b)(a+b)=(a-b)$$
So, we must have either $(a-b)=0$ or $(a+b)=1$. And since you mean different parts, I hope you mean $a\neq b$. So, you have just one sheep.